# How to nest attributes in form using devise without getting HashWithIndifferentAccess error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-forms

I am trying to expand the devise registration form to allow a new user to create an organization (company) at the same time they sign up.  I finally got the nested form fields visible (after reading several SO threads), but I have encountered an error that I believe to be associated with mass assignment.

I am a complete rails noob, still getting my feet wet.  Other SO questions have gotten me this far, but now I am just stuck.

Here are my current files:

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :organization
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 50
  validates_length_of :last_name, :maximum => 50

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :organization_attributes, :organization

end
```

**Organization Model**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, :foreign_key => "user_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

end
```

**Registration Form**

```
<h2>Register for a new account</h2>

<% resource.build_organization %>

<%= form_for(resource, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend class="hidden">Sign Up Form</legend>
    <h3>User Information</h3>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :first_name, :class => 'control-label' %>  
      <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :last_name, :class => 'control-label' %>  
      <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :email, :class => 'control-label' %>  
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :password, :class => 'control-label' %>
       <div class="controls">
         <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </div>
    </div>    

    <h3>Company/Organization Information</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for resource.organization do |fo| %>
      <div class="control-group">
         <%= fo.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
         <div class="controls">
           <%= fo.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
         </div>
       </div>       
       <div class="control-group">
          <%= fo.label :subdomain, :class => 'control-label' %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= fo.text_field :subdomain, :class => 'text_field' %>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="control-group">
         <%= fo.label :plan, :class => 'control-label' %>
         <div class="controls">
           <%= fo.text_field :plan, :class => 'text_field' %>
         </div>
       </div>
    <% end %>    

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Forgot Password?', :new_user_password, :class => 'btn btn-info' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

**Error Message**

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Organization(#70312257412900) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70312251932740)
Rails.root: /Volumes/www/projects/ror/testapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"SG/jlH2L3ATSqi1lBxlgbvWzx/sHVFlneX8vF/LKKZg=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"",
 "last_name"=>"",
 "email"=>"",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "organization"=>{"name"=>"",
 "subdomain"=>"",
 "plan"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I am sure I am missing something simple.  Looking forward to seeing what it is ;)

Comment: Hi,you can try organisation form and create user from that.Same example  https://github.com/iparam/time-tracker or (mongodb) https://github.com/iparam/samay

Comment: Try this: 
f.fields_for :organization, resource.organization do |fo|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
 
       f.fields_for :organization_attributes, resource.organization do |fo|
```